# How to lmport swift class into ViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**i used following code showing error that file not found.**

```
#import <SwiftDemo/ViewController-swift.h>
```

even ViewController.swift file is present in project, help me to sort out problem.

Comment: you imported file to ObjC project or Swift Project?

Comment: Try `#import "ViewController-swift.h"`

Comment: No its not working still showing same error.
its a swift project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to use Swift code from Objective-C. Is your product name "ViewController"? If not, then you are not importing the correct header. You should use the Xcode generated header `ProductModuleName-Swift.h` (replacing `ProductModuleName` with your specific product name).

In simplest terms, the `ProductModuleName` is just the name of your application. Example: my app is `Application` so this header is `Application-Swift.h`

Also, this header will connect ALL of your Swift to Obj-C, it is not file specific.

Please refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html) immensely helpful documentation piece on Swift/Obj-C interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

You should import a synthetic file generated by the compiler called `"<YourProductName>-Swift.h"`.

I think that this file is generated on the fly, but you can still inspect what it expands to by e.g. creating a dummy Objective-C file that contains just this:

```
extern int ____BEGIN_SWIFT_IMPORTS____; // dummy marker declaration
#import "<YourProductName>-Swift.h"
```

*(you should of course substitute `<YourProductName>`)*

and then by running the preprocessor on it (Product → Perform Action → Preprocess). All the output after the dummy marker declaration will come from the generated file. It's useful to see how Swift code marked with `@objc` gets translated to Objective-C declarations.

Comment: How can i create such a file?. I couldnt find any file with that name in my project. Is that specific for each swift file

Comment: Anil, that file is auto generated and maintained by Xcode and the compiler. It will connect Swift to Obj-C. In my answer above I have the link to the full Apple documentation on this which I found to be very helpful.

Comment: @IsaacDrachman I didnt get what they mean by ProductModuleName. Is that my swift file name?

Comment: No. In the simplest way, it's just your app's name. Ex: My app is called `Application`, then the file is `Application-Swift.h`. As a note, this file will connect to ALL Swift files in your product. It is not file specific.

Comment: @IsaacDrachman Thanks for your explanation. I think you could add these comments to your answer. It will be nice. +1 for you:)

Comment: Added a comment to show how to inspect what this generated file contains.